# Send ETH on echidna test

Tags: solidity, testing, assert, echidna

How do I make `msg.value` something (aka send some ETH) on the beginning of an Echidna test?

For example, if I have this function:

```js
function test() external payable {
   if (msg.value > 0) {
      assert(false);
   } else {
      assert(true);
   }
}
```

...how do I make it fail (aka run `assert(false)`)? Is it something in the config file? I went through its [docs](https://github.com/crytic/echidna/wiki/Config) but didn't find the option for it

Thanks!